# 3D modelling query

Tags: sculpting

I, being an ardent fan of Spiderman, decided to make a 3D model of him. After modelling and sculpting with the help of some alpha mask textures, I am almost close to finishing it, but I am stuck at the part where I have to draw the stripes (designs) and the spidey symbol (on his chest and back)[image]. How am I supposed to accomplish that?[image]

Comment: Are you sure you want to do it with mesh, as opposed to doing it with a bump map?

Comment: Anything that works, how am I supposed to do it? Can you please explain?

Comment: This kind of work is a lot easier to do with a texture that "pretends" to have depth.  Basically what you do is create an image on your model that represents which areas are high and which areas are low, and the renderer manipulates light values to make them look like that.  It's called a bump map, and I'm sure you can find lots about it.